# Java HttpClient trusted certificates

Tags: java, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

How do you specify a specific set of certificates for a java HttpClient or HttpURLConnection to trust?  I have seen some stackoverflow posts where people want to trust ALL certs, but that doesn't help.

Comment: http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2011/oct/18/httpclient-client-side-certificates/

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at this code example:
https://gist.github.com/erickok/7692592